# How to return object value in $lookup aggregation?

Tags: mongodb, lookup, aggregation

In mongodb, after doing an aggregation with $lookup, I would like the request to return object value from the specify field.

collection A:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("606d2881133c770654a4f649"), 
    "username" : "Hello",
    "mobile" : "812345678"
}
```

collection B:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f1e68f2a7418413b3646b51"), 
    "userId" : "812345678", 
    "contents" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5ef9d33f228f840bbd41649d"), 
            "name" : "Kelas 12"
        }
    ], 
}
```

Here is my code:

```
db.getCollection("A").aggregate([        { 
            "$lookup" : { 
                "from" : "B", 
                "localField" : "mobile", 
                "foreignField" : "userId", 
                "as" : "contents"
            }
        }
])
```

Result:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("606d2881133c770654a4f649"), 
    "username" : "Hello",
    "mobile" : "812345678", 
    "contents" : [

    ]
}
```

i got no result for contents.name from collection B. how to return object value in aggregation #lookup? thank you

Comment: Works fine [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/G56uNMnXPDF) how is that different from yours?

Comment: there's no value in contents

Comment: The code you provided when applied to the sample documents does not reproduce the problem.  Do you have any way to demonstrate the problem?